# Positiveness of inner product and Cauchy-Schwarz

Tags: linear-algebra, functional-analysis, solution-verification, hilbert-spaces

Suppose $V$ is a complex vector space and $(,)$ is an sesquilinear form on $V$ such that:

1.it is Hermitian, i.e., $(x,y)=\overline{(y,x)}$, or equivalently $(x,x)\in\mathbb{R}$;

2.it satisfies Cauchy-Schwarz inequality, that is

$|(x,y)|\leq\sqrt{|(x,x)|}\sqrt{|(y,y)|}$.

Define $V_1=\{x\in V\mid(x,x)\geq0\}$ and $V_2=\{x\in V\mid(x,x)\leq0\}$. Below is my attempted proof that these are subspaces, which, along with the fact that $V=V_1\cup V_2$, implies that either $V_1\subseteq V_2$ or $V_2\subseteq V_1$, and therefore $(,)$ is either positive or negative.

We conclude that any Hermitian sesquilinear form that satisfies Cauchy-Schwarz is either positive or negative. Since I could not find this anywhere it is probably **wrong**. Could anyone point out where did I make a mistake?

> Denote $\sqrt{|(x,x)|}$ as $\|x\|$. Suppose $(x,x)\geq 0$ and $(y,y)\geq 0$, then
>
>  $(x+y,x+y)=(x,x)+(y,y)+(x,y)+(y,x)$.
>
>  $(x,y)+(y,x)$ is real, and moreover by Cauchy-Schwartz
>
>  $|(x,y)|\leq\|x\|\|y\|$,
>
>  same for $(y,x)$. So
>
>  $|(x,y)+(y,x)|\leq 2\|x\|\|y\|$,
>
>  from which we have
>
>  $(x,y)+(y,x)\geq -2\|x\|\|y\|$
>
>  $(x+y,x+y)\geq (x,x)+(y,y)-2\|x\|\|y\|\geq 0$.
>
>  This shows $V_1$ is closed under summation. It is clearly closed under scalar product. Similar for $V_2$.

Comment: have check whether both requirements are compatible ?

Comment: @Physor Any positive inner product satisfies Cauchy-Schwarz inequality.

Comment: You made a mistake when you wrote $\sqrt{\lVert x\rVert}$ and $\sqrt{\lVert y\rVert}$, that ought to be $\sqrt{\lvert (x,x)\rvert}$ and similar for $y$ (modulus optional for $V_1$ but required for $V_2$). With that fixed, your argument works. Different argument: If $(\,\cdot\,,\,\cdot\,)$ weren't semidefinite it couldn't satisfy Cauchy-Schwarz. Pick $x,y$ with $(y,y) < 0 < (x,x)$ and consider the subspace spanned by $x$ and $y$. Since the form is hermitian there is a basis with respect to which the form has matrix $$\begin{pmatrix} 1& 0 \\ 0& -1 \end{pmatrix}\,.$$ Then take $(1,1),\, (1,-1)$.

Comment: You still need to get rid of the $\sqrt{\vphantom{X}\hphantom{X}}$.

Comment: @DanielFischer Thanks so much for correction. So this is actually true? I wonder why my professor told me this is true "in most cases but not in general"...

Comment: Unless I'm making a stupid mistake, it is true. As for why your professor told you "not in general", I guess the reason is "mistakes happen".